# Stored procedure in Oracle using Select Command and Variables giving error

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to figure out Oracle stored procedure as I am new to Oracle 11G

Here is my MS SQL stored procedure

```
Create procedure LoadLoginData
@username varchar(50),
@password varchar(50)
as
begin
select * from Employee_table where
username = @username and password = @password
end
```

When I used Oracle Scratch Editor I get this output

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LoadLoginData
(
  v_username IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
  v_password IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
  cv_1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS

BEGIN
   OPEN  cv_1 FOR
      SELECT * 
        FROM employee_table 
        WHERE Username = v_username
                AND PASSWORD = v_password ;
END;
```

when I call the Oracle procedure in C# it throws this exception

> "ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of
>   arguments in call to 'LOADLOGINDATA' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:"

Any idea how to figure this out?

My C# code

```
OracleConnection ocon = new OracleConnection(orastr);
        OracleCommand ocmd = new OracleCommand("LoadLoginData", ocon);
        ocmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        ocon.Open();

        try
        {
            ocmd.Parameters.Add("Username", nBo.username);
            ocmd.Parameters.Add("Password", nBo.password);
            OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(ocmd);            
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            oda.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            ocon.Dispose();
            ocon.Close();
            nBo = null;
        }
```

Comment: The error isn't in your stored procedure, it is in your call to the stored procedure.  What SQL are you using to call it?

Comment: I'm using Oracle Managed Drive ODP.NET Framework 4.5.2

Comment: What is the type of "nBo.username" or "nBo.password" ?

Can you try the same removing " DEFAULT NULL " from the oracle procedure ?

Comment: Both are in string format.

Comment: @SurajitBiswas I tried as you suggested and yet gives the same error

Comment: Your Procedure has 2 Input arguments and 1 output argument....your c# code has 2 input params but no output param...Error is natural, isn't it ?

Comment: Can you tell me how to make this right?

Comment: See, I don't know in C# but in Java, I 'ld have handled it it like 

`callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR);`

You just google if any such option is available in C# or not...

Comment: I think, this may help you...

`cmd.Parameters.Add("cv_1", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);`

If, my suggestion helps, please "upvote" my comments

Comment: @SurajitBiswas Hey, Thank you so much. It did help.

Comment: @RexJones
Please upvote my comments and answers

Comment: @SurajitBiswas I possibly can't. Not have that much rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **Procedure** has ***2 Input*** param and ***1 output*** param....your **C#** code has ***2 input*** params but ***no output*** param

In **Java** level, I would have handled it in this below manner :

**`callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR);`**

In **C#**, please look for the same thing (how to handle)...I suggest

**`ocmd.Parameters.Add("cv_1", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);`**